# extract the first and second node after a distinct of all nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

with the xml below, I need the first and second CICode after a distinct of all nodes:

```
<queryResult>
<result>

<row idx="1">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX1</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>A</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>WIP</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME1</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>
</row>
<row idx="2">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX1</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>B</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>Released</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME1</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>
</row>
<row idx="3">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX2</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>A</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>Released</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME2</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>
</row>
<row idx="4">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX2</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>B</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>WIP</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME2</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>
</row>
<row idx="5">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX3</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>A</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>Obsolete</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME3</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>
</row>
<row idx="6">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX3</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>B</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>Released</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME3</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>
</row>
<row idx="7">
  <CICode>CXXXXXXX3</CICode> 
  <CIRevision>C</CIRevision> 
  <CIState>WIP</CIState> 
  <CIName>CINAME3</CIName> 
  <CIBrand>Clarista</CIBrand> 
  <CIProductRange></CIProductRange> 
  <CICUST>KWARC001</CICUST>        
</row>

</result>
</queryResult>
```

as a result, I need to have :

```
CICODE~CXXXXXXX1,CXXXXXXX2~B,B~
CINAME~CINAME1,CINAME2~ ~ ~no
```

with the following xsl, I can extract all distinct nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<!-- Generate XML output from a queryResult document -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="queryResult/result[row]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Not defined</xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="CIProductRange" match="//*" use="local-name(.)"/>

<xsl:template match="CICode">


<xsl:if test="count(preceding::CICode)=0">

    <!-- list of CI codes -->
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;CICODE~</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="/queryResult/result/child::row">
        <xsl:variable name="currentCode1" select='CICode'/>
        <xsl:choose>

<!-- to get distinct CI codes -->
            <xsl:when test="count(following::CICode[.=$currentCode1])=0">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(preceding::CICode[.!=$currentCode1])=0">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$currentCode1"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="concat(',',$currentCode1)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>


    <xsl:for-each select="/queryResult/result/child::row">
        <xsl:variable name="currentCode1" select='CICode'/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentRevision1" select='CIRevision'/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(following::CICode[.=$currentCode1])=0">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(preceding::CICode[.!=$currentCode1])=0">
                        <xsl:copy-of select='$currentRevision1'/>

                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="concat(',',$currentRevision1)"/>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>~</xsl:text>


        <xsl:text>&#x0A;CINAME~</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="/queryResult/result/child::row">
            <xsl:variable name="currentName2" select='CIName'/>
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(following::CIName[.=$currentName2])=0">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(preceding::CIName[.!=$currentName2])=0">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$currentName2"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="concat(',',$currentName2)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>~ ~ ~no

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="queryResult">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
CICODE~CXXXXXXX1,CXXXXXXX2 ,CXXXXXXX3~B,B ,C~
CINAME~CINAME1,CINAME2 ,CINAME3~ ~ ~no
```

since I'm not too familiar with xslt, could you please help me to get the first and second CICode after a distinct of all nodes?

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT 1? I am also not sure what you are looking for, it would help if you explain your requirements a bit more in plain English based on the sample you have shown.

Comment: thank you for your reply. actually, I need to change this xslt to reply on a new requirements. in fact, the xml file contains all CICodes, and we can have multiple CICodes (same CICode but differents 'CIRevision','CIState'...). what I need is, for the CICode distinct list : CXXXXXXX1,CXXXXXXX2 ,CXXXXXXX3, only the first and second one: CXXXXXXX1,CXXXXXXX2. if it is not clear enough please let me know. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well, you haven't answered the question about the XSLT version, it seems in XSLT 2 and later you just can use `distinct-values(//CICode)[position() le 2]`.

Comment: sorry for not answering about xslt version. How can I know if i am limited to xslt1? regarding the expression you have provided, it works. however, how can I get the other information (CIRevision, CIState....) for each distinct CICode?